# How to match two values in MongoDB collection query?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, match

Here is my json code

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("6018430823544f4550724308"),
        "ownerId" : ObjectId("5fd471605dfe592674888e3b"),
        "screen" : {
                "ScreenName" : "Aud1",
                "Seats" : "200"
        },
        "shows" : [
                {
                        "showid" : ObjectId("601a16763028260ce88428f1"),
                        "MovieName" : "Joker",
                        "Format" : "2D",
                        "Language" : "English",
                        "Date" : "1/3/2021",
                        "ShowTime" : "2pm",
                        "Vip" : "400",
                        "Premium" : "300",
                        "Executive" : "200",
                        "Normal" : "100"
                },
                {
                        "showid" : ObjectId("601a16983028260ce88428f2"),
                        "MovieName" : "Churuli",
                        "Format" : "2D",
                        "Language" : "Malayalam",
                        "Date" : "02/2/2021",
                        "ShowTime" : "5pm",
                        "Vip" : "400",
                        "Premium" : "300",
                        "Executive" : "200",
                        "Normal" : "100"
                },
                {
                        "showid" : ObjectId("603d08f1cdaa7a26f8e17ebd"),
                        "MovieName" : "bigb",
                        "Format" : "2D",
                        "Language" : "Malayalam",
                        "Date" : "1/3/2021",
                        "ShowTime" : "10am",
                        "Vip" : "400",
                        "Premium" : "300",
                        "Executive" : "200",
                        "Normal" : "100"
                }
        ]
}
```

here i want to match `moviename==moviename` which user giving and `date==date` which user giving.
I want to get the result if this two condition is true

eg:

```
moviename==joker and date==1/3/2021
```

expecting result:

```
{
  "showid" : ObjectId("601a16763028260ce88428f1"),
  "MovieName" : "Joker",
  "Format" : "2D",
  "Language" : "English",
  "Date" : "1/3/2021",
  "ShowTime" : "2pm",
  "Vip" : "400",
  "Premium" : "300",
  "Executive" : "200",
  "Normal" : "100"
}
```

Comment: You can try using the [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html) operator with a _find_ method.

Comment: how can we use that..?

Answer (score 0):

Model.find({ MovieName : "Joker", Date:"1/3/2021"}) should give you the answer.